# Problems with pagination Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari

When I try to go to the next page, it redirects to board first page. This problem has appeared after adding sort and search. Maybe this is something wrong with routes.

**BoardController**

```
class BoardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:set_locale]
      redirect_to board_url(locale: params[:set_locale])
    else
      @search = Ad.published.search(params[:q])
      @ads = @search.result.page(params[:page])
      @search.build_condition
      @search.build_sort if @search.sorts.empty?
    end
  end

  def search
    index
    render :index
  end
end
```

**Board Index.html.slim**

```
= search_form_for @search, url: search_ads_path, method: :post do |f|
  = f.condition_fields do |c|
    = render "condition_fields", f: c
  .field
   = t('.sort')
   = f.sort_fields do |s|
    = s.sort_select
  .actions
    = f.submit t('.look_for')

  ...

 = paginate @ads
```

**_condition_fileds**

```
.field
  = f.attribute_fields do |a|
    = a.attribute_select associations: [:category]
  = f.predicate_select
  = f.value_fields do |v|
    = v.text_field :value
  = link_to t('.remove'), '#', class: "remove_fields"
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  get 'home/index'
  get 'board/index'
  scope '(:locale)' do
    resources :images
    devise_for :users
    resources :categories
    resources :ads do
      collection do
       get 'search'
      end
      collection { post :search, to: 'board#index' }
    end
    root to: 'board#index', as: 'board', via: :all
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you used `.paginate` method on `@search`?